# Working on a project on two computers at same time in Visual Studio

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017

My friend and I are working on an asp.net project and we want to work at same time, he is working on business classes and I want to use his methods. Is there any way to connect our computers, like local Team Foundation Server, and my computer gets latest changes from his computer?

I know git but the question is how can I run git on local and get the latest changes immediately?

Comment: Actually he should write methods in some classes and i should use them in other classes and as you know changes should be real time

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, unless you're actually doing something like remote pairing (if you want more than just screen sharing, I've used https://floobits.com/ for this). If you're trying to consume classes at the same time they're trying to write them, what happens if they need to change the API? Why don't you try pairing until you've got enough surface area on the application to work independently?

Comment: I dont want to change his codes, just use his methods, for example he writes a method for adding item to some table and i want to use it,I have a local lan network.

Comment: You could start by agreeing *interfaces*, so you can test your code against mocks while he writes the implementation, then integration test the two together when you both finish.

Comment: how about sharing project folder in LAN network and open Visual Studio in each computer?

Comment: That seems like a recipe for conflicts and weird bugs. Why are you so determined to do this?

Comment: a simple reason: we have a project contains this files: MyLogic.cs and Default.aspx my friend should work on MyLogic.cs and write methods like AddMessage(string title, string message) and i want to use it in Default.aspx.cs, if we work same time i can not have his methods and i should wait to complete his codes and sync but if i had realtime access to MyLogic.cs i could write my codes, dont i?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898731/working-on-a-project-on-two-computers-at-same-time-in-visual-studio?noredirect=1#comment74833846_43898731

Answer (score 0):

If both of your computers are on the same network, you can use git with his repo as a remote.  You will need to be able to access his repo over the network (SSH, file share, etc).  This allows you to pull directly from his git repo (after he commits; you can't pull his working copy).  It also gives you the freedom to *not* pull if he's making changes that would interrupt your workflow.

Otherwise, you could use a shared repository hosted somewhere (e.g. GitHub, Visual Studio Team Services, BitBucket, etc) and both push/pull as frequently as you agree to.  It also makes it easier to set up Continuous Integration so that you can make sure the repo is always in a buildable "clean" state before pulling changes locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use TFS, it has 2 version control methods for you: Git and TFVC. No matter which type of them, it needs to get down changes manually. When your customer commit and push the changes he made to Git repository, you need to pull down those changes to your local repository manually.

To know if there's some new changes submitted to TFS, you could use [TFS alerts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications#set-alerts-just-for-yourself). Create an alert when commits push into TFS. Then you will get an email notification when your friend push his commits.

[image]